# Getting two different Day values from Date()

Tags: php

So I have a database full of daily events that I want to show on a php page. I've connected to the database & populated the table - no problems. I then created a list of links that show the days of the week, so that the user can click on the day and the table will be populated by whatever event is scheduled for that day:

```
<ul id="day-list">
    <li><a href="?eventDay=Monday">Monday</a></li>
    <li><a href="?eventDay=Tuesday">Tuesday</a></li>
    ...etc etc... you get the idea.
</ul>
```

In the code prior to setting up the day list, I have this:

```
$theDay = isset($_GET['eventDay']) ? $_GET['eventDay'] : date('l', time())
// I've also tried date('l');
$data = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM 'my_table' WHERE 'event_day' = '$theDay';");
```

This is supposed to choose either whatever day the user selected, or today's day if $_GET['meetingDay'] is null/nil. It does actually works, however, I've notice about 9pm (my time) it switches over to the next day. I've also written *date('l')* and *date('l', time())* on the same page elsewhere and THAT displays the correct time, I just have this issue with $theDay variable.

I've looked into mysql & php timezones, and anything I research yielded me no results on my page (things like mysql's 'set time_zone' and php's 'date_default_timezone_set'). Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: run `SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;` is it your timezone?

Comment: Well.. it says SYSTEM when I run it in mysql. Which I can tell you right now that on the GoDaddy shared system, the timezone is MST... which is actually 2 hours behind me.

I also tried SELECT NOW()... and it returned 3 hours behind me, so I really dunno wtf is going on.

Comment: GoDaddy is the worst host on the planet. Flee why you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your line:

```
$theDay = isset($_GET['eventDay']) ? $_GET['eventDay'] : date('l', time());
```

... with these two:

```
$today = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Denver')); 
$theDay = isset($_GET['eventDay']) ? $_GET['eventDay'] : $today->format('l');
```

Replacing 'America/Denver' with whatever your timezone is.

List of supported timezones...
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Comment: Also ... I agree with Dagon about GoDaddy. :-/

Comment: Yes. I agree, however I'm doing this for a client, so GoDaddy is definitely not my choice. I changed long ago.

Comment: I understand ... I'm stuck there myself at work. Just venting a bit. :-)